# How can I store my data into the database with the entity manager?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine, entitymanager

This is the output of my variable `$data`:

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "form[username]" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(11) "form[email]" ["value"]=> string(7) "1@12.sw" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(15) "form[is_active]" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(26) "form[plainPassword][first]" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [4]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(27) "form[plainPassword][second]" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [5]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "form[id]" ["value"]=> string(1) "9" } [6]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "form[_token]" ["value"]=> string(43) "MdSCKxGkdFs2HPUSoM2vGidSRUmPgzZC3pZaW2wK2Rk" } }
```

I want to update now my data inside my database with the entity manager:

```
      $entityManager->persist($data);
      $entityManager = $data->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $entityManager->flush();
      $response = new Response();
      $response->send();
```

But I get the error message:

> EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object,
>   NULL given.

Comment: What does `$data` contain?

Comment: it is created with Ajax like this `var form = $(this).closest('form');var formData = form.serialize();`

Comment: No, it's not. That is Javascript code, and the other code snippet is PHP code. How **exactly** do you assign the value to `$data` in your PHP code?

Comment: like this: `$data = $request->request->get('data');`

Comment: And what exactly does it contain? A string?

Comment: Why don't you dump the variable to see what the content is?

Comment: Just to show you, maybe you know, why I get the error message, because I do not know

Comment: Well, I don't know either, but you should definitely dump the variable and see what it contains. Or you should start using a debugger like XDebug to further inspect errors in your code

Comment: Symfony does not magically transform the request body into an entity. So you cannot pass the unmodified incoming request to the entity manager. Looking at the format of the incoming data it seems that you already have a Symfony form type based on which the form is rendered. Is there a special reason you do not reuse that form type when handling the request?

Comment: I thought, there must be a way to store some data into the database from an object or something. I cannot solve this problem for a week now... Yes, the purpose because I am loading the form via Ajax so I have to post the submitted data somehow back to the server.

Comment: Ok, I have the dumped result of $data here: `array(7) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "form[username]" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(11) "form[email]" ["value"]=> string(7) "1@12.sw" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(15) "form[is_active]" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(26) "form[plainPassword][first]"

Comment: ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [4]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(27) "form[plainPassword][second]" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [5]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "form[id]" ["value"]=> string(1) "9" } [6]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "form[_token]" ["value"]=> string(43) "MdSCKxGkdFs2H2wK2Rk" } } `

Comment: Does this help to see what the problem is?

Comment: Yes, obviously your `$data` variable does not contain an entity. Have a look at the comment by xabbuh

Comment: Ok, thank you! This helps me to see what is the problem. I will now have to think how I can get the entity inside the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new entity if your data does not contain one. Get the correct data out of the form values and put them in the set methods. A small example below.

```
// Create new Entity
$entity = new EntityNameHere
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Use setter function from that Entity
$entity->setName($data['name']);
$entity->setPassword($data['password']); 

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: One question, I actually wanted to update my existing Entity `User()`. Is this possible too?

Comment: Ye you have to find the existing Entity, usually this is done on id. 
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['id' => $data['id']);

Comment: Is this correct? `$entity = new User();
          $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($data['id']);
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $entity->setName($data['name']);`

Comment: No remove the $entity = new User(); and replace with $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(AppBundle:User)->find($data['id']);

Comment: Unfortunately now I get an error message `Notice: Undefined index: id`

Comment: `[5]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "form[id]" ["value"]=> string(1) "9" }` I think I have to access to the id differently

Comment: Ye you have to get the data out somehow. Maybe try $data[5]['value']

Comment: Ok, I don't have error messages anymore. But the Entity User is not updated :(

Comment: Dump the $entity and see if the entity that you want to update is found.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(is_object($data)) {
        $metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
        $entities = [];
        foreach ($metadata as $entity){
            preg_match('/\w+$/',$entity->getName(), $o);
            $entities[] = $o[0];
        }
        if(in_array($data,$entities)){
            $em->persist($data);
            $em->flush();
        }
    } else {
        $query = null; //todo: $query
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping(); //todo: fill $srm
        $em->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm)->execute();
    }
```

Comment: THank you! I tested your code and get the error message `Notice: Undefined variable: em`

Comment: @Jarla         $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

Comment: Ok, now I get the error `An exception occurred while executing '':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty`